# Filtering Data between Specified Dates when Date is a Timestamp

Tags: hadoop, hive, dbd-pg

I'm trying to filter data between Jan 1st, 2021 and Jan 31st, 2021 in a Hive table. The column containing the date is in timestamp format (yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss). Is there a way to filter just based on year() month and date without inputting the timing? Any examples/sample code would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_date( dt_time timestamp) dt` to convert to date and remove time part.

```
select current_timestamp() , to_date(current_timestamp() )
```

[image]

```
Select * from table 
Where
To_date(input_datetime ) between to_date(from_datetime) and to_date (to_datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there anyway to include this in where the filter? I have millions of rows with same date but different timing. I just want to grab all the ones with date?

Comment: Can you use input_datetime between to_date(from_datetime) and to_date (to_datetime). So, if you have input as 03-mar-2021 9:30:00, and your from_datetime is 3-mar-2021 12:20:00 and to_datetime is 3-mar-2021 12:20:00, new sql i posted should work.

Comment: You have to use to_date() for all comparisons.